# SQL improve count(*) when filtering two nvarchar columns with LIKE 'prefix%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I am trying to improve the performance of a simple query that returns the count of rows where nvarchar(64) column `FromNumber` OR column `ToNumber` begins with a given prefix ('1002', in this case).

This is the current SQL query (as generated by Entity Framework):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT_BIG(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[SMDR_Call] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[FromNumber] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~'') 
           OR ([Extent1].[ToNumber] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~'') 
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',
       N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',
       @p__linq__0=N'1002%',@p__linq__1=N'1002%'
```

FWIW, the `FromNumber` and `ToNumber` columns are (persisted) computed columns. They have indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Call_FromNumber ON dbo.Call ( FromNumber ) 
    WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The times I get for this query are ~800 ms for a table with 2 million records.

Any suggestions for making this faster?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious suggestion is to write the query yourself. It's unrealistic to expect Entity Framework to write the fastest SQL.

For example

- You know that FromNumber is nvarchar(64) and not nvarchar(4000),
- The double SELECT serves no purpose,
- The wildcard expression doesn't use ~

Maybe this would be faster:

```
  SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
  FROM [dbo].[SMDR_Call]
  WHERE [FromNumber] LIKE '1002%'
```

Comment: I just tried that. The perf difference is so small it can be attributed to experimental error. There *is* a perf benefit, however, runing just the SQL query instead of running the parametrized SP (not sure why)

Comment: glad you found a speedup :-)